# Как организовать поиск и сортировка выборки из базы по валюте?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть таблица "Товаров" следующей структуры:

```
[id, price, price_currency]
```

И примерно следующего содержания:

```
[1, 100, RUR]
[2, 2, USD]
```

Валют может быть неограниченно много, но их котировки не хранятся в базе.

Собственно вопрос в том, как организовать хранение данных, либо работу с подобной таблицей так, чтобы было удобно сортировать и производить поиск используя единую валюту (на пример USD) в качестве базовой? Другими словами, нужно перед выборкой как то привести все `price` к единому значению в валюте USD используя внешнюю котировку.

Есть идея дополнить таблицу полем `price_base` и хранить в ней цену в базовой валюте, а так же пересчитывать это значение раз в сутки, но возможно есть решение проще?

Comment: А почему бы котировки не сохранить в базе, например так же, раз в сутки. Загрузить все котировки быстрее, чем используя их обновить все записи в БД, поочередно их от туда доставая и вычисляя

Comment: Не хочется использовать cron для обновления котировок, да и такая таблица потребует усложнение SQL в целом, так как необходимо будет джоинить ее к таблице товаров и пересчитывать стоимость по ней динамически.

Comment: А обновлять все записи в БД раз в сутки как будто вы хотите не через cron ...

Comment: Даже если бы жестко стояла задача раз в сутки обновлять поле цены в базовой единице я бы рекомендовал сначала загрузить котировки в БД. а потом на основе них обновить, так в разы (если ни в десятки раз)  быстрее, чем что то делать с записями на основании внешних данных

Comment: Я вообще не хочу обновлять что либо раз в сутки в БД, просто пока это единственное решение до которого я додумался, но мне оно тоже не нравится.

P.S. Вопроса оптимизации не стоит вовсе.

Answer (score 0):

Должна существовать таблица стоимостей валют в некоих базовых единицах. Хоть в рублях, хоть в тугриках... и соответственно все цены приводятся к этой базовой валюте или какой-то определённой выбранной - в запросе. А сама таблица либо обновляется, либо пополняется, если надо хранить историю (тогда кроме стоимости там ещё будет и штамп времени).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50469/discussion-on-answer-by-akina--------).

Answer (score 0):

1. хранить в базе в той валюте, в которой цена установлена, не пересчитывая
2. сделать таблицу с отношениями валют и датой обновления и обновлять, если устарела перед поиском
3. в поиске сделать да, чертовски сложный запрос с несколькими блоками ИЛИ (по количеству валют) в которых условия с коэффициентами
4. захочется быстрее - разделить товары по ценовым категориям с индексом